# Libgdx - Converting 2D map coords to 3D space coords

Tags: java, android, libgdx, coordinate-systems, perspectivecamera

I have an object moving about in a flat 2D coordinate system (0-1000,0-1000).

In a 3D space coordinate system, I have a sphere and a camera looking at the sphere.

I then want to convert these 2D coordinates to the 3D world/space coordinates and then move this object around the surface of the sphere. So, it's basically like converting Lat/Long into a 3D spacial coordinate.

Currently I'm using **setFromSpherical()** but maybe I'm using it the wrong way.

```
Vector3 my3DVector = new Vector3(0,0,0);
my3DVector.setFromSpherical((float)Math.toRadians(azimuthAngle), (float)Math.toRadians(polarAngle)).
```

Now my understanding of the 2 parameters are as follows:

- Azimuth angle is in Radians, between 0-2PI, and is effectively LONGDITUDE
- Polar angle is in Radians, between 0-1PI, and is effectively LATITUDE

As my 2D grid (lat/long) grid size is 1000x1000, I calculate azimuth and polar like this:

```
float azimuthAngle = (flatPos.X/1000) * 360;
float polarAngle = (flatPos.Y/1000) * 180;
```

This gives the normalised versions of the 2D grid values (Azimuth 0-360 degrees, Polar 0-180 degrees), which are then converted to Radians, and passed to **setFromSpherical()**. Currently, this works, and the object is moving around the surface of the 3D Sphere, however, when the 2D X value passes 1000, it wraps back to 0 and then the calculated 3D Z value jumps, so the object jumps to the other side. The object wrapping in the 2D Y value works fine though...

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Why do you use 360 for the azimuthAngle but 180 for the polarAngle?

Comment: That's what the documentation says: Azimuth 0-2Pi, Polar 0-1Pi. Although, saying that, I changed thte `polarAngle` to *360 and it doesn't jump about anymore it loops around the whole sphere correctly. Saying that, My "linear" pathing around the globe is tracking oddly, so now I've seen there's a separate issue, which is probably due to the various converting methods of flat 2D coords to a 3D spherical one. I'd need to introduce proper Mercator projection mapping I guess