# 3D sphere object orbit modelling

Tags: java, android, 3d, libgdx, 3d-modelling

following on from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34297871/libgdx-converting-2d-map-coords-to-3d-space-coords) , I have a separate issue that I want to check.

I want to redo my calculations of having objects orbit a sphere on their own unique orbit, at various heights (radius) and angles (orbital plane). My previous post explains the method I am using, however I am getting quite a bit of unexpected behaviour, which I think is due to the mapping method I use. Objects start "turning" on their own and going off in changing directions when uncommanded.

SETUP:

- I have a flat 2D grid of 1000x1000 where I keep track of objects
- I then map these to the sphere and convert to 3D coords.

However, this is probably causing issues with a flat 2x2 not being able to be wrapped onto a sphere without huge distortion, so need to convert it to Mercator Projection, then wrap that onto the sphere.

Before it gets too complicated, would it be far easier to just deal with Matrix4 or Quaternions and represent everything by rotations instead? I still need to keep track of all objects, and the position on the sphere (for simplicity, lets say on the surface), but I need to be able to modify the objects orbits. For example, modify their height, or direction (orbital plane).

Can someone suggest a cleaner way to represent these valyes locally? I can see this getting very messy otherwise.

Many thanks,
J